# Hamiltonian and Lagrangian for a particle on a ring

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, wick-rotation

In the book [Condensed Matter Field Theory (A. Altland & B. Simons)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521769752)(page 498, 2nd edition) they suggest the following Hamiltonian and Lagrangian for a particle on a ring in the presence of a magnetic field (with a vector potential $A$):
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}
&=
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
-i \partial_{\phi} - A
\right)^2\tag{9.1}
\\
\mathcal{L}
&=
\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2-i A \dot{\phi}\;.\tag{9.4}
\end{align}

They also suggest as an exercise for the student to verify that the Legendre transform indeed gives the above results, so I've tried!

The momentum is given by
\begin{align}
\pi
&=
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}
=
\dot{\phi}- i A\;,
\end{align}
then, the Legendre transform of $\mathcal{L}$ is
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}
&=
\pi \dot{\phi} - \mathcal{L}
\\
&=
\dot{\phi}^2
-
i A\dot{\phi}
-
\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2
+
i A \dot{\phi}
\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}
\dot{\phi}^2
\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\pi + i A
\right)^2
\; .
\end{align}
Now, finally, $\pi\mapsto-i\nabla$ in the position representation ($\hbar=1$) where for a particle which constrained to live on a ring, only the angular derivative survives, such that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}
&=
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
-i \partial_\phi
+iA
\right)^2
\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
A
-
\partial_\phi
\right)^2
\;,
\end{align}
which is obviously not the given Hamiltonian. For a plus-minus issue: I wouldn't bother... but the lack of the imaginary part is a matter of a big deal.

I feel that that I'm missing something extremely simple (or something subtle? idk), but either way, I would be grateful if anyone could point out the missing link.

Comment: The Lagrangian is written in imaginary time. However, passage to the Hamiltonian formalism should be done in real time.

Comment: May be the answer is given by @Meng Cheng's comment as [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313921/) also.

Comment: @MengCheng You are right, in real time it works, but why is it like this? Shouldn’t it in principle work for it too? What changes?