# In path-integral, when do we have to insert fact $i$ in front of the action $S$ in the exponent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, action, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

I have got stuck in these concepts for a fews days: Wick rotation, Euclidean spacetime and QED in gravity.

Generally, in Minkowski space time, there is a factor $i$ in front of the action $S$, e.g., the path integral looks like
\begin{equation}
\int \mathcal{D}{(\mbox{fields})} \exp\{iS_{Mink}\}
\end{equation}

Now we perform a Wick rotation $t=-ix^4$, the metric shall go from $(-,+,+,+)$ to $(+,+,+,+)$ which is positive-definite and is known as "Euclidean spacetime". Doing some algebra, the path-inetgral will look like
\begin{equation}
\int \mathcal{D}{(\mbox{fields})} \exp\{-S_{Euc}\}.
\end{equation}
where $-S_{Euc}=iS_{Mink}$ and $Euc=$ Euclidean spacetime.

My confusion is: **Does the name "Euclidean spacetime" depend on the positivity of metric?** Suppose I have a Dirac theory in gravitational field of **positive-definite metric** $g^{\mu\nu}$
\begin{equation}
S_{Dirac}= \int d^4x \sqrt{g}~~i\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}(\nabla_{\mu}-ieA_{\mu})\psi,~~~\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}=2g^{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}
Which one should I choose for path-integral, $\exp\{{iS_{Dirac}}\}$ or $\exp\{-S_{Dirac}\}$?

Answer (score 3):

1. The Minkowski Boltzmann factor is always $$\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S_M\right)~=~\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\int\! dt_M~L_M\right)  \tag{1}$$
   while the Euclidean Boltzmann factor is always $$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\hbar}S_E\right)~=~\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\hbar}\int\! dt_E~L_E\right). \tag{2}$$
   Concerning the Wick-rotation
   $$\begin{align} -S_E~=~&iS_M, \cr t_E~=~&it_M, \cr L_E~=~&-L_M,\end{align} \tag{3}$$
   see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106292/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. In a nutshell, the imaginary unit $i=\sqrt{-1}$ in the Minkowski Boltzmann factor (1) is a remnant of the $i$ in the unitary evolution operator $$\hat{U}~=~\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}\Delta t_M\right),\tag{4}$$
   cf. the standard derivation of the [path integral formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) from the operator formalism.
3. Concerning the $i$'s in the Minkowski Dirac action $S_{{\rm Dir},M}$:

   - It's EL equations should be the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation).
   - It should be real up to boundary terms.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. 1. By the "Boltzmann factor", are you talking about statistical mechanics? I have less knowledge about that. 2. But to me, it seems the appearence of  factor $i$ depends on which spacetime we are working in? 3. In an asymptotically euclidean gravitational field, there would be no $i$, since my action should reduce to $S_E$ on the boundary in stead of $S_M$, right?

Comment: 1. It is just a name here. 2. It depends on the spacetime signature, which I assume is either Minkowski or Euclidean. 3. Right.

Comment: I think OP’s question was — what if we defined QFT to live on Euclidean space rather than Minkowski (as opposed to analytically continuing Minkowski QFT to Euclidean signature)? I don’t know if this is possible, in fact, some of the axioms of QFT depend on Minkowski signature and seem to not have a Euclidean counterpart. However, quantum gravity models that live on Euclidean space exist, eg Ponzano-Regge. These are defined on a differential manifold and signature is a constraint on their dynamics. And in the path integral of Ponzano-Regge you still have a factor of $i$, not $-1$.