# Computing the functional integral over the gauge and ghost fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, yang-mills, ghosts, functional-determinants

In Peskin&Schroeder page 517 the authors mention that the functional integration of the gauge fields and ghost fields yields the following determinants
$$
(\det[-\partial^2])^{-d/2}\cdot(\det[-\partial^2])^{+1}.\tag{16.43}
$$
This comes from the following terms in the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}_{\text{free}}=-\frac{1}{4}(F^a_{\mu\nu})-\bar{c}^a\partial^2\delta^{ac}c^c
$$
where we take $g\rightarrow 0$. Now to compute the functional integral we take
$$\begin{aligned}
\int\mathcal{D}A \mathcal{D}\bar{c}\mathcal{D}c\; exp\left({iS[A,c,\bar{c}]}\right)=\int\mathcal{D}A\mathcal{D}\bar{c}\mathcal{D}c\exp\left(-i\int d^dx\left[\frac{1}{2}A^a_\mu(x)(\partial^2g^{\mu\nu}-\partial^\mu\partial^\nu)A_\nu^c\delta^{ac}+\bar{c}^a(x)\partial^2\delta^{ac}c^c(x)\right]\right)
\end{aligned}$$

I'm don't understand how these give the determinants mentioned in the book. Specifically, the exponents(which is the important part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 517, the author tells you that the calculation is carried out in [Feynman-'t Hooft gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#:%7E:text=Most%20quantum%20field%20theory%20computations,the%20Yennie%20gauge%20%CE%BE%20%3D%203.&text=The%20auxiliary%20field%2C%20sometimes%20called,to%20obtain%20the%20previous%20form.). The problem with your last equation is that the propagator of the photon is singular before imposing gauge fixing conditions. i.e it has zero modes, and the path-integral is not well-defined.

On page 513, there's another hint for the calculation in the bosonic sector. Equation (16.29) says $$\langle A^{a}_{\mu}(x)A^{b}_{\nu}(y)\rangle=\int\frac{d^{d}k}{(2\pi)^{d}}\frac{-i}{k^{2}+i\epsilon}\left(g_{\mu\nu}-(1-\xi)\frac{k_{\mu}k_{\nu}}{k^{2}}\right)\delta^{ab}e^{-ik\cdot(x-y)}.$$

The Feynman-'t Hooft gauge is when $\xi=1$. i.e $$\langle A^{a}_{\mu}(x)A^{b}_{\nu}(y)\rangle=\int\frac{d^{d}k}{(2\pi)^{d}}\frac{-i}{k^{2}+i\epsilon}g_{\mu\nu}\delta^{ab}e^{-ik\cdot(x-y)}.$$

This time, the photon propagator is non-singular and has an inverse. You only need to calculate the following functional integral of the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)) in the bosonic sector:
$$\int\mathcal{D}[A]\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int d^{d}x A_{\mu}^{a}(x)g_{\mu\nu}^{E}\delta^{ab}\Box A^{b}_{\nu}(x)\right),$$

where $g^{E}_{\mu\nu}$ is the [Euclidean metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106345/185558) after a wick rotation. What Peskin and Schroeder didn't say in their book is that equation (16.43) is actually in Euclidean signature. Later, they mentioned in the next paragraph that "**this physical effect was illustrated, using the language of Section 9.4, in Problem 9.2.**"!!! There, in Problem 9.2, readers are asked to perform the same path-integral in Euclidean signature. **Please check page 312, 313, and 314.**

Now, taking the coupling $g=0$ is essentially going back to the Abelian case, i.e. QED where photons and the ghost fermions decouple, and you can ignore the Killing form $\delta^{ab}$. Then, in such a case, turning to the Euclidean signature, the full partition function should be written as $$\mathcal{Z}=\int\mathcal{D}[A_{1}^{E}]\ldots\mathcal{D}[A_{d}^{E}]\int\mathcal{D}[c]\mathcal{D}[\bar{c}]\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int d^{d-1}xdx^{d}(A_{\mu}^{E}\Delta\delta^{\mu\nu}A_{\nu}^{E}-\bar{c}\Delta c)\right),$$

where $d^{d-1}xdx^{d}=dx^{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{d-1}\wedge dx^{d}$ is the Euclidean volume form, and $x^{0}_{E}=x^{d}$, and $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator (the Euclidean counterpart of the [d'Alembert operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) in Lorentzian spacetime) in the Eulidean space, and $\left\{\delta_{\mu\nu}\right\}=\mathrm{diag}(1,\cdots,1)$.

Then, using the [Gaussian integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory) and the [Berezin integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) you should find $$\mathcal{Z}=\left(\mathrm{Det}\left(-\Delta\right)\right)^{-d/2}\mathrm{Det}(-\Delta).$$

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand this now. My concern was with the determinant being raised to the power of $d/2$. In your answer if you want to compute the d dimensional functional integral you need to include $d$ integration measures for all your gauge field components right? So you would actually have $\mathcal{D}A_1^E\mathcal{D}A_2^E\ldots\mathcal{D}A_d^E$.

Comment: @twistedmanifold Yes. Remember that $\mathcal{D}[A]=\prod_{x,\mu,a}A^{a}_{\mu}(x)$. The most important thing is that you need to wick rotate everything into the Euclidean space. Otherwise you don't have the power $d/2$, and the sign for the ghost fermion would also be wrong.