# Wick's rotation, unitary transformation and symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, wick-rotation

The [Wick's rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106345/159335) $W$ facilitates dealing with integrals in the Minkowski space by rotating time into the Euclidean space. As this rotation in time is performed within integrals, one can view that as a change of integral's variables, and subsequently, the integrated results in the Minkowski and Euclidean space are the same.

On the other hand, spatial rotations $\cal R$ can be viewed as transformations that, depending on the properties of our system of interest with Hamiltonian $H$, may play the role of symmetries such that
$${\cal R} H {\cal R}^{-1} = H.$$

My questions are

1. Can we consider the Wick's rotation combined with spatial rotation as a spacetime transformation for a time-dependent $H$? i.e., writing
   $$(W{\cal R}) H (W{\cal R})^{-1}=H~? $$
2. If yes, can you suggest a time-dependent Hamiltonian in which the Wick's rotation is its symmetry?

Sharing further insights regarding this issue is very appreciated.

Comment: Wick rotation, as I know it, is a specific trick we can do to shift the contour of integrals. How do you intend for it to act on your $H$ operator? [Note that time evolution using $H$ in Minkowski time and in Euclidean time looks very different, in real-time you get phases, in euclidean time you get exponential suppression of states]

Comment: One possibility is relaxing the Hermiticity of $H$. With complex spectrum, a dynamical phase and a decay of state may be interchangeable.