# Continuum limit of lattice field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lattice-model, wick-rotation, lattice-gauge-theory

Just a simple question for lattice QCD experts, is continuum limit of lattice field theory a **relativistic** quantum field theory?

Because i heard that lattice QCD is done in imaginary time, producing a ground-state (lowest-energy state) in infinite temporal extend limit. And that two-point correlation functions computed in imaginary time can be analytically continued to real-time.
But for massive particles (such as quarks) to be relativistic, their kinetic energies should be equal to or greater than $mc^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really specific to lattice theory - doing stuff in "imaginary time" means you're doing Euclidean QFT. This isn't so much "relativistic" or "non-relativistic" as it is just a formal computation - no one thinks this Euclidean theory directly describes any physical setting.

However, analytic continuation of the results to "real time" then gives you quantities for a relativistic Minkowskian theory. It is not at all obvious that analytically continuing the results of the a priori unphysical Euclidean theory should have anything to do with what the physical Minkowskian theory does, but this is the miracle of [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) - it turns out that this actually works (although in many cases you need to think a bit carefully about what Euclidean theory corresponds to what Minkowskian theory, see e.g. [this question and its answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106292/50583)), and the formal statement of this is called the [Osterwalder-Schrader theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Osterwalder-Schrader+theorem).

Comment: Well, my question was more about continuum limit of lattice field theory. Is only a data extrapolated in continuum limit gives a relativistic QFT after analytic continuation? Does it mean that a lattice with any finite lattice spacing is non-relativistic?

Comment: @Peter I don't understand the distinction you're making here - the continuum limit of a Euclidean lattice field theory is presumably a Euclidean QFT, no? Wick rotation doesn't care *how* you produced your Euclidean QFT.

Comment: @Peter there’s two issues that are separate, the continuum limit and wick rotation. At finite lattice spacing, your Lorentz/Euclidean group of symmetries is broken by the lattice and you get discretisation artifacts. And usually people use relativistic to mean the real-time theory, but this is separate

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear.