# Wick rotation of Electromagnetic Field Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, wick-rotation

So i will directly to the problem. I am not getting how, when we Wick rotate, the EM action should go to (the correct answer)

$$ S_E = \int -d^4 x\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{Wick} S_M = \frac{1}{4} \int d^4 x F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$$

So that $S_E = -S_M$

But mine obtained is not exactly this! See, let $x^0 = -it$, so

$$dx^0 = -i dt \\
F_{i j}F^{ij} = F_{i j}F^{ij} \\
F_{i 0} F^{i 0} =  F_{i j}F^{ij} \\
F_{0 0 } F^{0 0} = F_{0 0}F^{0 0 }$$

Where i used the fact that $A_{0} \rightarrow i A_0, A^0 \rightarrow -i A^0$.

So the action transforms to

$$S_E = -\frac{1}{4}\int d^4 xF_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{Wick} S_M = \frac{i}{4} \int d^4 x F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$$

That is,

$S_E = -i S_M$

As we can see, the correct answer (the first equation) is not exactly equal to mine answer. In fact, the only difference is the $i$. The problem is that i don't know where i made a mistake, to be honest.

I have looked for any source involving Wick transformin the electromagnetic Lagrangian, but it seems that it is not a wwidely used tool, so i couldn't find out where i am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to Perform Wick Rotation in the Lagrangian of a Gauge Theory (like QCD)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106292/2451)

Comment: @Qmechanic I still can't understand what step i did that was wrong, i don't think it should be closed.

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to i) define unambiguously the arrow notation and what is Minkowski/Euclidean, and ii) point out the difference between the supposedly right and wrong results.

Comment: @Qmechanic Ok, done

Comment: Is the correct answer from a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic Introduction to AdS/CFT, H. Nastase. Pg 10, 12 and 22

Comment: Do you mean https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0689 ? Which pages? Which eqs?

Comment: @Qmechanic i was talking about the book. But you can use the paper, see the 1.26 eq

Comment: $-S_E=iS_M$, cf. text below eq. (1.6).

Comment: @Qmechanic This is so strange. I though that i should derive this expression. In fact, i did. So i need, after that, to take the action $S_E(x_0 = -it)$, and still multiply it by $-i$? (for example, the result i get, if i multiply by -i, ends in the "right answer")This is a definition?